# Is it possible to step into a member function defined in a .dll file?

Tags: c++, debugging, dll, visual-studio-2015, 360-degrees

I downloaded an SDK from NVIDIA and I'm using Visual Studio 2015 to run the demo project files provided in the SDK.

The demo project files in the SDK worked as expected until I made some small changes in the code (If you'd like details about the changes, please see last paragraph).

After making these changes, a line in the code seems to run forever. Using the debugger I found that there's a member function in that line of code that is not returning anything and therefore the program flow is just stuck at that line. I tried stepping into this function but it's defined in a `.dll` file that came with the SDK.

Visual Studio tells me that the symbol file is not loaded and the PDB file cannot be found on the Microsoft Server. The debugger lets me see the disassembly code but I don't know if I can identify the problem using that.

So now I'm stuck at a line of code because the member function defined in a .dll file won't return anything and just keeps on running (I've left it running for over an hour and still it didn't return anything).

I want to identify the reason why this is happening, but I'm unable to see the source code of the member function so I have no idea what's happening inside the member function or how to debug it. Is there any way I can identify the cause of this problem? Is it possible to somehow see the source code of the member function in a way that I can understand what is going on?

More details on changes I made:

I've separated this from main body of the question because I don't see it as being very relevant but it may be useful for the answerer. The SDK stitches videos together into a single video (creating 360 view videos). The demo project works fine as long as I use the demo video files. The video files are fed into the project using command line arguments. When I feed my own video files to the demo project, that's when I face this problem, otherwise the member function returns successfully and the project successfully creates a stitched video. The only thing I changed is the input to the project (i.e. the video files), I haven't changed the source code at all.

Comment: It is possible, however you need source code and debug symbols for this dll.

Comment: @VTT As far as I know, the SDK doesn't come with debug symbols or source code for the dll. So in that case would it be impossible?

Comment: Well, you can always dig into assembler a bit. But most likely fixing an issue that you are facing does not require going into dll function at all. e.g. you are passing wrong arguments, your video has an unsupported format and so on.

Comment: @VTT Right. The documentation only mentions that input videos should be .mp4. I've tried multiple permutations of arguments to try to get it working, but this ends up being a trial-and-error sort of approach, and so far it hasn't worked. I'm just trying to find other ways to get to the solution.

Comment: "mp4" is a very broad term, I bet they also put a rather strict requirements on codec and colorspace used. You can use mediainfo to show all the relevant information about video format of particular file. You should compare parameters of demo video with yours.

Comment: You may want to ask this here: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/

Comment: @VTT Thanks for the suggestions. The codec for the demo video files is H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (AVC1) and my video files' codec is Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (H264). Looks very similar at first glance, I guess I need to look this up.

Comment: @drescherjm I have already, without any success. Unfortunately that forum is not as active as something like stackoverflow. Here's a link to my post there: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1016303/nvidia-vrworks-360-sdk-nvvs_stitcherfeedinput-how-to-debug-member-functions-that-live-in-dll/#5177113

Comment: @VTT Thanks for guiding me to the solution. The problem was the minor difference in the codec name. I used the same codec as demo file to encode the images into the video and it works now. Whew!

Comment: @db7638, If this issue has been resolved, you could post your solution as an answer, and then mark it, so it could help other community members who meet the same issue:)

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT Thanks for the reminder, comments like yours are helpful for new users of this website like me. I've added my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by VTT and Aganju, I cannot step into the member function defined in the DLL unless the source code is provided to me with the DLL. This answers what I asked. For my specific case, I was working with NVIDIA VRWorks 360 Video SDK, the problem was caused by not having the right codec for the video files that get stitched. Although this is mentioned nowhere in the SDK documentation, the video codec that should be used is H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (AVC1).

Answer (score 0):

If the provider of the DLL doesn't deliver the source code, you obviously can't see it. That would be the common way to handle it - unless they are open source, their source code is the company's intellectual property, so of course they are not showing it to you.

If it is open source, you typically can download the debug-DLLs (which contain the source code). Microsoft also delivers many runtime DLLs in version with source code (but of course not Windows itself). Check in the SDK if there is a debug version of that DLL, and link with it instead of the one you are currently using.

So, in a nutshell, you can't see it unless they give it to you.